# mvn tomcat7:deploy takes too long to deploy?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat7, maven-tomcat-plugin

I am using tomcat7-maven-plugin to deploy my spring batch admin application,

below is my configuration in pom,

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Tomcat 7 has a different manager path - text - than other versions -->
                <url>http://localhost:8081/manager/text</url>
                <username>myusername</username>
                <password>mypassword</password>
                <path>/${project.build.finalName}</path>
                <update>true</update>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I am running,

```
mvn clean install tomcat7:deploy
```

Though it completes successfully, it takes too long to complete this command nearly (4-5 min).

Below is the output of command. It takes lot of time to receive response after uploading war file. You can observer below output, it took 4.16 min.

It worked pretty fast till it displays the message "uploaded .." but after that it keeps waiting for response for 4-5 min.

I need to deploy application on multiple servers (5 servers) so it will take 25 min which is too long for only deployment.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.st:batch:war:1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-core:jar -> version ${spring.batch.version} vs (?) @ line 125, column 15
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-infrastructure:jar -> version ${spring.batch.version} vs (?) @ line 129, column 15
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.mortbay.jetty:maven-jetty-plugin is missing. @ line 182, column 12
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin is missing. @ line 189, column 12
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-admin-parent:1.3.0.RC1, /home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/springframework/batch/spring-batch-admin-parent/1.3.0.RC1/spring-batch-admin-parent-1.3.0.RC1.pom, line 245, column 12
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin is missing. @ org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-admin-parent:1.3.0.RC1, /home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/springframework/batch/spring-batch-admin-parent/1.3.0.RC1/spring-batch-admin-parent-1.3.0.RC1.pom, line 253, column 12
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building st 1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ batch ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/ubuntu/java/spring/batch/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ batch ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 105 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ batch ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 53 source files to /home/ubuntu/java/spring/batch/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ batch ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/ubuntu/java/spring/batch/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ batch ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ batch ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) @ batch ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [batch] in [/home/ubuntu/java/spring/batch/target/batch-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [/home/ubuntu/java/spring/batch/src/main/webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [130 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: /home/ubuntu/java/spring/batch/target/batch-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] WEB-INF/web.xml already added, skipping
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ batch ---
[INFO] Installing /home/ubuntu/java/spring/batch/target/batch-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war to /home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/com/st/batch/1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT/batch-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] Installing /home/ubuntu/java/spring/batch/pom.xml to /home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/com/st/batch/1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT/batch-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.1:deploy (default-cli) @ batch >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ batch ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 105 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ batch ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ batch ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/ubuntu/java/spring/batch/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ batch ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ batch ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] Skipping execution of surefire because it has already been run for this configuration
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) @ batch ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [batch] in [/home/ubuntu/java/spring/batch/target/batch-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [/home/ubuntu/java/spring/batch/src/main/webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [73 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: /home/ubuntu/java/spring/batch/target/batch-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] WEB-INF/web.xml already added, skipping
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.1:deploy (default-cli) @ batch <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.1:deploy (default-cli) @ batch ---
[INFO] Deploying war to http://localhost:8081/batch-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT  
Uploading: http://localhost:8081/manager/text/deploy?path=%2Fbatch-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT&update=true
Uploaded: http://localhost:8081/manager/text/deploy?path=%2Fbatch-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT&update=true (16362 KB at 116869.5 KB/sec)

[INFO] tomcatManager status code:200, ReasonPhrase:OK
[INFO] OK - Deployed application at context path /batch-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 04:16 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-07-23T11:49:33+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 23M/303M
[INFO] -------------------------
```

Comment: That's because `tomcat7:deploy` waits for app to be started insied of Tomcat which may take long time.

Comment: If I start tomcat manually, app starts as soon as tomcat is started. Is there any reason why it happens when maven plugin used?

Comment: Obviously when you redeploy application it will stop old version, undeploy it, then deploy new version and start it

Comment: First i would suggest to clean up my build which has so many warnings in it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following commands to deploy your app. It will help with the length of time it takes to redelpoy, but it will not stop the length of time it takes for the `Uploading:` & `Uploaded:` parts since its waiting for Tomcat.

`mvn -T 1C install tomcat7:redeploy-only -DskipTests -offline`

`-T 1C`: This means that we will use 1 thread per core on the deploying machine